Python max() function not working some of the time
I am using the max() function to find the highest key in a dict - with some it works and with others it doesn't.  Here is a program demonstrating the problem:
dict1 = {'A14':'Ahmed Jamal', 'A27':'Ahmet Gulbay', 'A12':'Ali Farka Toure',
         'A43':'Alison Trewhela', 'A33':'Amy Winehouse', 'A4':'Andras Schiff',
         'A15':'Antonio Carlos Jobim', 'A11':'Bob Dylan', 'A8':'Charles Mingus',
         'A52':'Charlie Parker', 'A6':'Chet Baker', 'A38':'Count Basie',
         'A24':'Dave Brubeck', 'A47':'Dire Straits', 'A41':'Dizzy Gillespie',
         'A18':'Don Cherry', 'A23':'Duke Ellington', 'A29':'EST',
         'A20':'Geoff Sample', 'A21':'Goldfrapp', 'A45':'Hinny Pawsey',
         'A1':'Horace Silver', 'A13':'J S Bach', 'A22':'JJ Cale',
         'A30':'Jan Garbarek', 'A44':'Jef Gilson', 'A46':'John Cale',
         'A25':'John Coltrane', 'A3':'Kieth Jarret', 'A26':'Lou Reed'}

dict2 = {'A50':'Michael Brecker', 'A7':'Miles Davis', 'A10':'Beethoven',
         'A34':'Muddy Waters', 'A2':'Murray Perahia', 'A31':'Oscar Peterson',
         'A32':'Paolo Conte', 'A37':'Paul Simon', 'A9':'Pink Floyd',
         'A28':'Playlist', 'A17':'Rolling Stones', 'A51':'Ry Cooder'}

dict3 = {'A48':'Satie', 'A39':'Simon & Garfunkle', 'A36':'Sourakata Koite',
         'A35':'St Germain', 'A40':'Stephan Grappelli', 'A24':'Paul Martin', 
         'A17':'Rolling Stones', 'A51':'Ry Cooder'}

dict4 = {'A10':'Horace Silver', 'A22':'Murray Perahia', 'A3':'Kieth Jarret',
         'A44':'Andras Schiff', 'A15':'Tord Gustavsen Trio'}

for dict in (dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4):

    hkey = 'A' + str(int(max(dict.keys())[1:]) + 1)
    print(hkey)

output thus
    A9
    A10
    A52
    A45

I checked for any inconsistency in the typing and can find none

The dict keys are strings, not "embellished" numbers. 'A9' as a string is the largest key in dict1, for example, because '9' is the largest digit, not because 9 is the largest numerical component.

Thanks @chepner. Presumably the alphabetic order of two-digit numbers would be 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21 etc ?

Yes. Since every string starts with A, it's essentially irrelevant, and so you are just sorting numbers as strings.

Assuming you want to sort by number, ignoring any leading character(s), you need a key function:
max(dict1, key=lambda k: int(k[1:]))

Assuming all keys are of the form A[::digit::]+, this key function strips the A and connects the remaining portion to an integer to use in any comparisons.

You are mistaken about what max is doing.
max is returning the "largest" string.
That is to say, the string that would occur last if the strings were sorted alphabetically.
